# Where in macOS do I put files I want to load into my iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to create a directory and fill it with images to load into a Collection View in my app, since it doesn't appear possible to load all images from a group in xcassets in any way other than one at a time by name.

However, all the info and documentation on the matter seems to talk about the **on-device** directories you're supposed to use to read and/or write files programmatically.

So if I want to create a directory and fill it with files while developing my app on macOS and then have that directory transfer over to my app's internal directory structure upon the app's release, where do I create this folder on macOS?

Comment: I think you have some massive confusion going on. What is the actual underlying thing you want to do? Load some images fromxcassets into a collection view? Then ask that, post code for that and say what you want to do with it and why its not working.

Comment: You can certainly put a directory-full of images into your app's bundle and then load them at runtime, but you are better off using an asset catalog. It makes life much easier. You need to explain what it is that you need to do. If it's just load images into the cells of a collection view then you can simply create an array of image names and load them into your collection view cells as needed.

Comment: Well, right now, I only have 20 images, and creating a manual array of names would already be a pain. In the future, I could have hundreds or even over a thousand images in total. Filling the Collection View with images by name really doesn't seem like the practical, optimal approach.